# Play AngularUI view transition in the right place

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-router, zurb-foundation

I want to have a transition between me views. I'm using Foundation For Apps, so I use their Front Matter solution, however I have the same problems using the standard procedure.

When I animate between the views, the animation works fine but is in the wrong place. After playing, the animated view "snaps" to the right place.

You can see the problem in the image below. Not only should the animation play under the menu, but also should it end where it's supposed to be at the end.

[image: The transition]

Comment: can you put snippet for the same

Comment: I don't have any of that code anymore, but it was because I used Foundation for Apps and that project is pretty dead.